# Cartoon that had a villain who was a woman, but looked like she was made out of crystal shards or something similar

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I’m looking for the title of an '80s or '90s cartoon.

This cartoon that had a villain that was a women but she looked like she was made out of crystal shards or something similar. It was set in space and her planet was all rocky.

I’m sure it was an American cartoon but it was played in Australia as well I watched it in the 90s

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this? In the '90s, or later than that? Also, do you know which channel or channels you would likely have seen this on?

Comment: I am getting  a _Space Ghost_ vibe... Was the animation kind of crappy?